# Switch platform spotlight not working?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-nativeclient

this is the built version

[image: built version]

this is the game view version

[image]

settings

[image]

it was working fine before and building the same untill i switched platforms and built web player version and google native client version, i cannot find anything on it, before i built the other version it was just for android, im trying to revert back so they will build the same on android again, im looking for some insight on this, thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have to adjust your quality settings. In Unity 3.5.x go to *Edit / Project Setting / Quality* and ensure that more than 0 pixel lights will be rendered and shadows are enabled. I have not yet upgraded to Unity 4 but it should be similar there.

Be aware that this affects rendering performance.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i just changed it, and edited the question with settings, its still the same way, any other suggestions?

Comment: nevermind you were right, just the higher settings were enabled for android